# Defining a generic nested map in thrift (JAVA - C++)

Tags: java, c++, hashmap, thrift

I want to be able to define a json formated string in thrift

```
struct Message{
    1: i32 msgId;
    2: map<string,object> data;
}
```

I know the above representation is wrong. But is there a way to have the data defined as JSON object?

EDIT:

A better way to ask the question:

How can I represent nested data structures in thrift. For example, the map field 'data' in the above struct can have any have any levels of nesting and any type of value (primitives, list, set, map, custom object) for each key. Is this possible to do in thrift?

Comment: I don't think Thrift targets JavaScript... how would this be useful at all?

Comment: I agree. This is not useful. Considering thrift was specifically designed for strong typed languages. This is some requirement that I had to handle and just wanted to see were there any approaches.

Comment: Are you trying to express an arbitrary JSON object in Thrift? Or just transport the JSON string? Both are doable, although I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: @Kerrek JSON does not necessarily imply Javascript. I've used JSON to transport data between Java and C++.

Comment: @Alan: I am trying to send an arbitrary JSON object in thrift. The point is this IDL is common to multiple interfaces between multiple JAVA and C++ components. So I thought the data part of the exchange should be quite generic. Samples of defining arbitrary thrift JSON object will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked a question like: how do we define an object as part of thrift struct that can have any level and any type of nested objects within it.